# Does iText (any version) work on Windows Azure websites?

Tags: itext, azure-web-app-service, itext7

There are many limitations with the Azure App Service (formerly websites), so I was wondering if iText's PDF creation tools still worked. Specifically, I will be converting HTML to PDF, including all manner of styles and images.

Neither rotativa nor Pechkin work on Azure App Service due to its limitations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There are many limitations with the Azure App Service (formerly websites), so I was wondering if iText's PDF creation tools still worked.

Based on my test with following sample, I can use [iText 7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/7.0.4-netstandard) to generate PDF file, and it works fine on Azure App Service Web App.

```
var path = Server.MapPath("test.pdf");

FileInfo dest = new FileInfo(path);

var writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
var document = new Document(pdf);
document.Add(new Paragraph("hello world"));
document.Close();
```

**Generated PDF:**

[image]

Besides, I am using the basic feature of iText, which works fine on [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). If any advanced features of iText can not work on sandbox, you can try another hosting options (such as Cloud Services, Virtual Machines).

Comment: seems a long time you posted it, but was your plan basic and higher or consumption?