# How to store Generated pdf on deployed website with Itext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, itext

I am trying to write to a pdf and send it in an email.I am able to implement this on my local machine. The problem is when I deploy to azure I am not sure where to store the pdf .  I have seen one question regarding this
 and tried this solution from stackoverflow -
[Does iText (any version) work on Windows Azure websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471073/does-itext-any-version-work-on-windows-azure-websites).

```
var path = Server.MapPath("test.pdf");

FileInfo dest = new FileInfo(path);

var writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
var document = new Document(pdf);
document.Add(new Paragraph("hello world"));
document.Close();
```

I get an error

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'D:\home\site\wwwroot\Email\test.pdf'.

Comment: consider using a `MemoryStream` as target of `PdfWriter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create the Pdf in memory and stream the content to the asp.net output stream.

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
document.Open();
document.NewPage();
...
...
document.Close();

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
byte[] pdfBytes = ms.ToArray();
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", pdfBytes.Length.ToString());
Response.OutputStream.Write(pdfBytes, 0, (int)pdfBytes.Length);
```

Comment: After Mkl's suggestion I found  essentially the  same solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196059/itextsharp-sending-in-memory-pdf-in-an-email-attachment?rq=1), without the last half .

Comment: @Curious in that case please either accept this answer (as it's similar enough) or create your own answer to eventually accept.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your issue is related with the file path.
If I use the path like  `Server.MapPath("Azure_Example1.pdf")`, I also get the same error as you.

[image]

I suggest you could try to use the relative path like `Server.MapPath("~/Azure_Example1.pdf")`. The '`~/`'  points to the project root directory.

You could also set a break point to check the value of path by using remote debugging.

[image]

I have created a simple demo, it works fine on my side. You could refer to.

1. Install the **iTextSharp** 5.5.13 nuget package in **Manage Nuget Packages**.
2. Use the following code:

   ```
       var path = Server.MapPath("~/Azure_Example1.pdf");
       FileInfo dest = new FileInfo(path);
       FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
       Document doc = new Document();
       PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
       doc.Open();
       doc.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World")); //change content in pdf
       doc.Close();
   ```

Finally, you could see the pdf file has been stored in root project directory.

[image]